# How can I detect use of the Alexa Simulator

Tags: simulator, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing for Alexa, specifically the visual elements shown on the Show device.

If you produce visual elements and deliver them to a device that does not support them you get an error.

The simulator does not support visual elements and so I write code to get around this issue.  Unfortunately that causes the final delivery to fail when I just use an Echo.

I don't want to write test code and then change it for live delivery.  Is there a way I can detect that the simulator is being used so that I can isolate code for this instance.

Answer (score 0):

The Alexa Request JSON includes device information under `context`:

```
{
   "context":{
       "System": {
           "device":{
               "supportedInterfaces":{
                    "Display":{},
                    "AudioPlayer": {},             
                    "VideoApp":{}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can find this with `event.context.System.device.supportedInterfaces.Display`

`supportedInterfaces` can include `AudioPlayer`, `Display`, and/or `VideoApp`

If it is not listed under `supportedInterfaces`, then it is not supported.

---

The Alexa Simulator should provide "Display" under supported Interfaces.
[See here:](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/devconsole/test-your-skill.html#alexa-simulator-limitations)

> **Note:** The Alexa Simulator behaves like a device with a screen, such as the Echo Show or Echo Spot. This means that the context.System.device.supportedInterfaces property in the request sent to your skill always contains the Display interface. In addition, the simulator is not supported for use in multiple browser tabs at the same time.

---

In order to get the Alexa Simulator to display like an Echo Show, you need to enable "Echo Show Display" at the top.

[image: Alexa Simulator Options Bar]

Comment: This I am aware of, the issue is that the simulator does not indicate that it is a supported interface for display and so my code would usually not show display outputs.  Unfortunately this means I can not test display elements in the simulator (even though the simulator support this).  

This is why I specifically wanted to determine whether or not the simulator is in use.

Comment: By "the simulator" do you mean echoism.io?

Comment: The simulator is the one in the Alexa Skills kit

Comment: I have to admit that I have not heard of echoism.io.  So I just tried it.  It seems to me that it is audio only.  I am testing the visual part of Alexa and so this simulator is insufficient.  Are there simulators that provide access to all capabilities (both verbal and visual)?

Comment: I have only used the built-in Alexa Simulator and Echoism.io. I've added some more information to my answer in hopes that helps to solve your problem.